# CSS: What's a better way to overlay an image over a div border?

Tags: css

I have a div with a solid border and want to overlay a centered logo over top of it.

Right now I have a solution that just embeds the image on the page and then moves it into position with: 'margin-top:-13px;text-align:center;'

https://jsfiddle.net/christophera/43Ljmoh9/

```
.inside-article {
  margin-top:20px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-color: red;
}
.pos-logo {
  margin-top:-13px;
  text-align:center;
  }

<div class="inside-article">
<div class="pos-logo">
<img style="width:120px;"  src="https://test.consumer.press/img/consumer-press.svg" />
</div>
</div>
```

I've tested with chrome and edge desktops and it works... I'd have to adjust the margin-top to work on my phone using @media...  But... well, is this a good way to do this, or do you have a better method?

thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change `margin-top: -13px` with the `transform: translateY(-50%);` and you will get exactly the same result, and you won't need to calculate the negative pixels.

Comment: I tried each of these solutions on the site. This was the easiest and the one that worked the best in practice without interfering with anything else. Thank you all for the different answers and takes on this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo element for border and it is 100% responsive.

set its position to absolute and `top:50%` to stay in middle and `transform:translateY(-50%)` to center its position and set `z-index:-1` to go behind the layer

Make sure to set `vertical-align: middle` for the `img` so that it stays in mid line

```css
.inside-article {
  margin-top:20px;
  position: relative;
}
.inside-article::before {
  content: '';
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.pos-logo {
  text-align:center;
  }
  img{vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="inside-article">
<div class="pos-logo">
<img style="width:120px;"  src="https://test.consumer.press/img/consumer-press.svg" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display:flex` in your container, you'll be able to centre your image in the middle of it, regardless of its dimensions.

Use the `:before` pseudoselector on your image container to draw your line, and position it absolutely with percentages – this means it'll also always be in the middle if your div changes its height.

```css
.inside-article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.inside-article .pos-logo img {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
}

.inside-article .pos-logo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inside-article">
  <div class="pos-logo">
    <img src="https://test.consumer.press/img/consumer-press.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple when you use the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`  elements.

```css
.inside-article {
  border: none;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
}

.pos-logo {
  margin: auto;
}

.logo-image {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="inside-article">
  <legend class="pos-logo">
    <img class="logo-image" src="https://test.consumer.press/img/consumer-press.svg" />
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

**NOTE:**
`fieldset` elements are intended for form elements and labels, so if you really need to match the standards, this solution is not recommended.

But this code is the shortest above all, and that's something :)

Comment: Thank you, I considered this but working with a wp template and trying not to make changes to the html. I like the idea though. Investigating and testing the other solutions.